# color by a column name using plotly

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a dataframe in the below format:

```
 id     distance    value    is_match
 1      234         0.8      True 
 2      314         0.5      False
 3      904         0.1      False
 4      123         0.4      False
 5      287         0.9      True
```

I tried plotting it using plotly. X axis would have "distance", y axis would have "value" and color the circles using "is_match". Used the below code:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(df, x='distance', y='value', color='is_match')
```

But this does not color code based on "is_match" column.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: The shown code and dataset seems to work correctly for me. I get [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjYZ8.png) (versions: plotly 5.3.1 pandas 1.3.4)

Comment: @HenryEcker is there a limit on the dataframe size? I have a dataframe of 800 rows and it does not plot everything

Comment: I don't know if there is a limit on DataFrame size. I do know that if there were such a limit it would be much higher than 800 rows. The titanic dataset plots fine and that has 891 rows (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- works fine.  Have generated much larger dataset as per comments from you sample
- when number of points 10**5 then second trace (True) dominates as it is above first trace (False)

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id     distance    value    is_match
 1      234         0.8      True 
 2      314         0.5      False
 3      904         0.1      False
 4      123         0.4      False
 5      287         0.9      True """), sep="\s+")


ROWS = 10**4
df = pd.DataFrame({"distance":np.random.randint(df["distance"].min(), df["distance"].max(), ROWS),
             "value":np.random.uniform(df["value"].min(), df["value"].max(), ROWS),
             "is_match":np.random.randint(0,2,ROWS).astype(bool)})

px.scatter(df, x='distance', y='value', color='is_match')
```